# Problem with sessions on nginx using xenForo

Tags: php, authentication, nginx, session, xenforo

I have an major problem with xenForo Logins on nginx and tried everything foundable out.

The xenForo is not the problem it workes fine on an other apache server but I need to move it to nginx.

I'm using the newest nginx and php7.1, php-fpm and all requested sources for xenForo are installed. Other Sites (like Roundcube) works fine. I use the default site config for all sites with - so far - no problems.

Now, for the problem. When I logi to my xenForo ACP the login works fine but I get immediately logged out. Some times I get logged out a  few minutes later, when I change the site. On the user site the login works pretty fine als long as I stay on the forums pages (as the forum, member page, profiles) and get logged out when I use a 3rd party site programmed by me (worked fine on apache without problems).

The xenForo Filesystem is owned by www-data:www-data and chmod permissions are set correctly.

In the php.ini file I set the correct path for the sessions to /var/lib/php/sessions and with an external simple script I proved that the sessions are saved correctly with no problems.

No errors displayed.

As long as I can say, everything works fine just the Login makes real trouble and I get out of ideas.

Maybe someone here can help me and find something I didn't see.

Kind Regards,

//Edit:
I found out that this Problem Not appears on the user site if the "Keep me logged in" button is ticket. Ob ACP there is no such button.

//Edit:
I found out, that the Cookie didn't get dropped, it's still there.

//Edit:
The timezones are correct.